# Does ray tracing have any speed ups in algorithm running time in the frequency domain?

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity, fourier-transform

Could ray tracing be Fourier-transformed so that all calculations are done in the frequency domain?

I think ray-tracing a set of rays $S$ from the eye into the view frustum might be more efficient for large scenes when there's a lot of repetition so for instance a large landscape with trees with leaves, of the same few species.

Any counter thoughts?

Comment: honnestly, your question suggests that you don't understand the fourier transform, or the ray tracing. 
in a first time, consider a scene where every objects are spheres. what would be the best possible algorithm (and complexity) for rendering it by mean of ray tracing ? what if you consider reflection, refraction and even worse : diffusion ?

Comment: and a fundamental question : is the ray tracing rendering operator linear ? (the fourier transform being a linear operator)

Comment: You say I don't understand these things, but you didn't say why.  Obviously an MD FFT would be applied to all scene data, transformation matrices, virtual view frustums (I guess maybe a view/projection matrix), and ray vectors.  I understand that there are efficient "usual spatial domain" representations for 3D data such as BSPs and AABBTrees.  All in all I understand enough not to think I know the answer to this question, son!  So essentially I schooled you son, I mean...  Represent all your data, also including color / difussivity as one large vector and use MD FFT to get to the domain.

Comment: if you imagine computing the discrete Fourier transform, it means you sampled/gridded your 3d scene. hence, an interesting question would be : is it really a good idea sampling the scene before rendering it with ray-tracing ? (how would you do that ? for what kind of scene ? triangles ? spheres ? what about the normals, the diffusion or reflection properties ?)

Comment: and if you are interested in 3d programming, you should look at GPU gems, ShaderX, GPU Pro, these are more or less the reference books, all available online.